# Determining the range of angles for which it is possible to construct a triangle wth given measurements

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, $AB = 10$, $BC = 5$, $CA = x$, and $\angle BAC = \theta^\circ$.
>
> 1. Show that $x^2 - 20 x \cos\theta + 75 = 0$.
> 2. Find the range of values of $\cos\theta$ for which the above equation has real roots.
> 3. Hence find the set of values for $\theta$ for which it is possible to construct $\triangle ABC$ with the given measurements.

Can anybody help me with parts 2 and 3? I get an inequality with 2 variables which is sort of unreasonable. We understand $x$ is a length and cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic equation has real roots if its discriminant is positive.

$D = b^2 - 4ac$

$400\cos^2θ - 300 > 0$

$\cos^2\theta> 3/4$

$\cos θ > \sqrt{3}/2$ or $\cosθ < -\sqrt{3}/2$

$θ > π/6$ or $θ < -π/6$

Comment: Thankyou, i had tried that just could not convince myself